# System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed only when running through visual studio

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, mediatr

I'm registering some services for MediatR with reflection in my web api app with .NET6.

When I'm running the application from docker/command prompt the application running successfully.
When I'm trying to run the application from visual studio with/without debugging I'm getting the next error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Verte.UnifiedCommerce.MessagingModel.WarehouseManagement.AsnCommands.AsnGenerationCommand' while attempting to activate 'Verte.UnifiedCommerce.DomainModel.Cqrs.Commands.Events.SagaInitiationCommand`1[Verte.UnifiedCommerce.MessagingModel.WarehouseManagement.AsnCommands.AsnGenerationCommand]'.

My code to register the services is:

```
var eventType = typeof(IApplicationEvent);

var assemblies = typeof(AsnGenerationSaga).Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()
    .Select(a => Assembly.Load(a))
    .ToArray();

var commands = assemblies.SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
    .Where(t => !t.Name.Contains("ClientNotificationCommand") && !t.IsInterface && !t.IsAbstract && t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.FullName == eventType.FullName) && (t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Command)) || t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ModificationCommand))))
    .ToArray();

var events = assemblies.SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
    .Where(t => !t.IsInterface && !t.IsAbstract && t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.FullName == eventType.FullName) && t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(SagaEvent)))
    .ToArray();

services.AddMediatR(typeof(ProductsReader).Assembly);

foreach (var type in commands)
{
    var sagaInitiationCommandType = typeof(SagaInitiationCommand<>).MakeGenericType(type);
    var irequestHandlerType = typeof(IRequestHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(sagaInitiationCommandType, typeof(Unit));
    var sagaEventInitiatorType = typeof(SagaEventInitiator<,>).MakeGenericType(sagaInitiationCommandType, type);

    if (sagaEventInitiatorType != null)
    {
        services.AddTransient(typeof(IRequest<Unit>), sagaInitiationCommandType);
        services.AddTransient(irequestHandlerType, sagaEventInitiatorType);
    }
}

foreach (var type in events)
{
    var sagaPublishCommandType = typeof(SagaPublishEvent<>).MakeGenericType(type);
    var irequestHandlerType = typeof(IRequestHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(sagaPublishCommandType, typeof(Unit));
    var sagaEventInitiatorType = typeof(SagaEventInitiator<,>).MakeGenericType(sagaPublishCommandType, type);

    if (sagaEventInitiatorType != null)
    {
        services.AddTransient(typeof(IRequest<Unit>), sagaPublishCommandType);
        services.AddTransient(irequestHandlerType, sagaEventInitiatorType);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

Replace:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IRequest<Unit>), sagaInitiationCommandType);
```

With:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(ICommand<Unit>), services => Activator.CreateInstance(sagaInitiationCommandType));
```